# Como llamar una fila de MySQL a una pagina php

Tags: php

No tengo un codigo para eso y queria saber como hacerlo es que tengo un carrito de compras y una pagina de productos, lo que quiero hacer es que cuando le presione al boton (de mi producto) me redireccione a una pagina donde esten las especificaciones de ese producto pero con uso de una consulta de la BD

```
<?php

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `products`");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
            echo "
          <div class='product_wrapper'>
             <form method='post' action=''>
                 <input type='hidden' name='code' value=".$row['code']." />
                     <div class='image'><img src='".$row['image']."' />
                     <div class='name'>".$row['name']."</div>
                     <div class='price'>$".$row['price']."</div>
                     <a href='especificaciones.php' class='info'>Especificaciones</a>
                <button type='submit' class='buy'>Agregar al carrito</button>
             </form>
          </div>
          </div>";    
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

La linea de "a" osea especificaciones es el link a otra pagina y todo el "echo" es la del producto que llame de mi BD y necesito saber como hacer para que al pinchar el boton me mande la informacion de ese producto a otra pagina, no se si me explique disculpenme si no fue asi[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que se me ocurre, es que en el link (etiqueta a) utilices una variable para almacenar el id del producto, luego en PHP accedes a la variable mediante la variable global [$_GET](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.get.php) para extraer su valor.

Tu código quedaría algo así:

```
<?php

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `products`");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo "
        <div class='product_wrapper'>
            <form method='post' action=''>
                <input type='hidden' name='code' value=".$row['code']." />
                <div class='image'><img src='".$row['image']."' />
                <div class='name'>".$row['name']."</div>
                <div class='price'>$".$row['price']."</div>
                <a href='especificaciones.php?producto=".$row['code']."' class='info'>Especificaciones</a>
                <button type='submit' class='buy'>Agregar al carrito</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        </div>";    
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Ahora en tu página especificaciones tendrías que iniciar con tu consulta SQL para traer los detalles de tu producto, para esto accedes a la variable $_GET['producto']. La cual tiene el valor del id del producto que el cliente selecciono.

```
<?php
    $detalles_productos = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE id_producto = $_GET['producto']");
    //Aquí ya va el resto de tu pagina de detalles del producto
?>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\AlphaTech\especificaciones.php on line 77

Comment: Me sale eso y el codigo del select lo puse asi $detalles_productos = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `code`='$_GET['producto']'");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)

Comment: Eso se debe a que estas colocando la variable entre comillas simples (') si una variable de PHP la colocas entre comillas simples es tratada como texto y no como una variable. si lo que deseas es concatenar el query con la variable tu código debería ser así:
$detalles_productos = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM products WHERE code=".$_GET['producto']);

Answer (score 0):

En esta pieza de codigo debes indicarle el Id de producto a mostrar en el archivo de especificaciones

```
  <a href='especificaciones.php?product=".$row['id_product']."' class='info'>Especificaciones</a>
```

Luego en tu archivo especificaciones.php Tendrias que anexar el siguiente codigo para obtener el Id enviado

```
$product=$_GET['product'];
```

Despues de eso está demas indicarte que harás un select a la base de datos para obtener los datos con el producto que te indican